# sass lightness function query

Tags: css, sass, conditional-formatting

I am just learning sass and have come across the lightness @function which seems like a really useful tool.

My question is is there a way such a function could be used to determine the contrast between color and background in cases where a background image is used. I have read that the value is calculated from a hsl value. I am guessing this would require some form of image evaluation of each images. The use case I have in mind is a netflix clone I am doing just for some practise. The banner has some images from the tmdb api but some of them make the default white text difficult to read. Is there a way to evaluate images with the lightness function with some conditional.

If not does anyone have a suggestion about what could be used as an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that there is anyway that Sass/CSS can provide you with on-the-fly analysis of the background color of an image.  Your best bets would probably be to use a translucent box around your text to sidestep the issue altogether, or leverage [`the <canvas> API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) in order to  assess the background-color (this is going to be a relatively involved/complicated approach).

Comment: By "a translucent box around your text" do you mean something with a low opacity such as 0.2 that would make the text visible when the image is lighter? Yeah that's not ideal. I will look into the canvas api thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try this, as long as you compute the colours ahead of time SASS can help you here: https://css-tricks.com/programming-sass-to-create-accessible-color-combinations/ Accessibility is more important than cool effects, though, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. I don't know how to compute the colors ahead of time.

Comment: Now you know why many sites put their text on some sort of dark-opacity overlay when there is an image as background. Simply because there isn't any easy way to determine if text can be read over an image.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, you can achieve this by combining the `if` and `lightness()` to determine if the background is dark or light and make the text the opposit.

```
$banner-text-colour: hsla(300, 76%, 72%, 1);

@function set-banner-text-color($colour) {
  @if (lightness($colour) > 50) {
    @return #000000;// if backgorund is light dark text
  } @else {
    @return #ffffff;// if background is dark light text
  }
}

.banner-text {
  background: $banner-text-colour;
  color: set-banner-text-color($banner-text-colour);
}
```

[jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/axsvwdet/1/)

**EDIT**:
If you're looking for a solution based on an background image you can try the`filter:invert()` option together with `background-clip`. Check the below article.

[methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds](https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/)

Comment: This would only work would only work if you hard coded the $colour variable though wouldn't it? I am looking for something that works dependant on the darkness of the image that the text is in front of.

Comment: @MarkScholes, in this case Sass can't help you. Since it's a CSS precompiler. You'll need JS in this case. Sass can only compare variables.

Comment: @Becky thanks, I am not sure how that would work but I will investigate

Comment: @Becky man that is cool, I don't know if I will end  up using it but it was worth asking to read about that; thanks

Comment: The CSS filter approach is definitely a cool, CSS-based option; excellent callout.  As others have pointed out, though, remember to keep accessibility/readability in mind-- this solution will work great on a simple image with mostly solid colors, but a complicated photograph or pattern _might_ negatively affect legibility.